# Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability error from Google Play Store

Tags: react-native, flutter, cordova, ionic-framework, huawei-mobile-services

#### Problem Describe:

Recently, some developers have reported that they want to update their app(s) on Play Store,
However, it receives rejection from Google with the title ***Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability***, said that their app(s) contain an Implicit PendingIntent issue. And they need to fix this issue before the deadlines shown in their Play Console, or app(s) may be removed from Google Play.

[image]

Similar Question: [Google denied update due Remediation for Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68088627/13329100)

Comment: please modify your question so that it only contains the question/problem and move the "solution" into an answer. By design, this ensures improved search indexing and your answer will help more users with this problem.

Comment: thanks@tao, i will updated this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As@[tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/tao) mentioned, let me post the solution here.

---

#### Problem Reason:

HMS Core Push kit earlier than ***5.3.0.304*** version、Analytics Kit earlier than ***6.0.0.301*** version and Account kit earlier than ***5.3.0.305*** version  contain the Implicit PendingIntent issue.

#### Solution:

Push Kit SDK [version 5.3.0.304](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-app-version-0000001074227861#section3358144513280)、Analytics Kit SDK [version 6.0.0.301](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050705116#section5452175218817) and
Account kit SDK [version 5.3.0.305](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050048874#section1554552952318) have been released and fixed the *Implicit PendingIntent* issue. They've been tested and verified by developers and can be approved by Google for release.

If you are currently using the **plug-in**(such as React Native, Cordova, Ionic,Flutter), Before the new version of those plug-in released, Huawei also provide a **workaround solution**(By manually changing the version number).

The following describes the modification method (based on the 5.x plug-in):

- **React Native**：

1. After the HMS Core plug-in is installed in the RN, the plug-in package is stored in node_modules/@hmscore.

   [image]
2. You need to modify the `build.gradle` file in the *node_modules/@hmscore/react-native-hms-account/android* directory (taking the Account Kit plug-in as an example):

   Open the `build.gradle` file and change the SDK version in dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hwid:5.0.3.302'
}
```

3. After the update, run the following command to start compilation again. The plug-in downloads the new SDK:

   `react-native run-android`

---

- **Cordova/Ionic**

1. If you have installed the plugin as Huawei document describred, the plugin should be saved in node_modules/@hmscore folder.

   [image]
2. You need to modify the `plugin.xml` file in the `node_modules/@hmscore/cordova-plugin-hms-push` directory. (The following uses the Push Kit plug-in as an example)

   Open the `Plugin.xml` file, search for the keyword `framework`, and find the SDK to be modified.

```
<framework src="androidx.core:core:1.3.1"/>
<framework src="com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.2.0"/>
<framework src="com.huawei.hms:push:5.0.2.301" />
<framework src="resources/plugin.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>
```

Change the version number to the new one and save it.

3. Go back to the application root directory and delete the `platforms/android` and `plugins/cordova-plugin-hms-push` folder.

   [image]
4. Run the following command in the root directory:

   *Cordova*：

   `cordova platform add android`

   `cordova run android --device`

   *Ionic(Cordova)*：

   `ionic cordova platform add android`

   `ionic build`

   `ionic cordova run android --device`
5. Ionic (Capacitor) operates in different ways:

   ①. Delete the `capacitor-cordova-android-plugins` folder from the android directory.

   [image]

   ②. Modify the `plugin.xml` file according to the description in step 2.

   ③. Run the following command:

   `ionic build`

   `npx cap sync`

   `npx cap open android`

   ④. Recompile in the Android Studio

---

- **Flutter**

  You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68660177/13329100).

#### Summary

The plug-ins above are used in open source mode, so developers can modify them directly.

However, the Xamarin plug-in is published in Nuget Package mode. Therefore, you cannot modify the SDK version. If this problem occurs, please feel free to contact us.